# Find non local phone numbers

Tags: regex, grep

I have the task of finding phone numbers, but I do not want to find phone number that have area codes. I am using grep

So far I have figured out that i can use
`[0-9]{3,3}\-[0-9]{4,4}` to find the local phone numbers, But I'm not certain how to negate the non-local phone numbers.

Ex:

- 555-5555 is a local phonenumber
- 555-555-5555 is a nonlocal phonenumber.

Comment: The regex will not match both

Comment: US-only numbers where they follow either the 7- or 10-digit format, without prefixes such as `+46`, etc.?  Also, do you have access to grep's `-P` flag, to use PCRE expressions?  `grep -P ...`

Comment: can you provide a sample data?

Comment: If the only difference is the length of the number (7 digits vs. 10 digits), you can simply by checking the length of the phone number string. The complexity is completely depends on the source data - i.e. how messy the input would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is fine but you can leverage anchors to only match you local numbers:

```
^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$
^------ Here ------^
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wO7rA8/1)**

But above regex will work if your line only holds your numbers, so if you have multiple numbers in the same line you could use a negative lookbehind like this:

```
(?<!-)[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wO7rA8/2)**

Btw, as **[ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072112/ghoti)** stated in his comment you don't need to escape the hyphen unless it's used in a character class, so you can shorten your regex as:

```
^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: Pretty sure the hyphen in the middle of this expression does not need to be escaped.

Comment: @ghoti nice eye, didn't see that. Thanks. will update it.

Comment: Since this is for grep, the negative look-behind would need to use grep's PCRE extension `grep -P` so it could match functionality from the pattern you posted on the regex101 site.

Comment: @OnlineCop, Note that grep does not include support for PCRE on all platforms.  ERE is universal though, so a solution using ERE is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -v` negates matches, so if you search for

```
grep -v '[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'
```

Then all your 10-digit numbers are NOT matched, leaving only the 7-digit numbers.

However, this is only when you have well-formed phone numbers (such as from a generated script). You will have to account for these, and other, variations:

```
(800) 555-5555
800-555-5555
800 555 5555
8005555555
```